# How to encourage a user to fit with SE norms?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

We have a new user among us who I recognised from [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) as one who never marks answers as correct, even in one case where they said "Exactly what I was trying to find". At least they added "Thankyou".

While this may not bother some of us, it rubs me the wrong way. Maybe this says more about me than they.

The extra 15 rep is not so important to me. With n00bs you often get that. But usually they get the hang of how things work if they stick around. But this user has been on Stack Exchange for over a year. Multiple senior users have asked them to select the answer deemed correct, but there has been no change observed.

Not everyone here follows the behavioral norm for bicycles.SE; this community is in general much more gentle than robust communities such as the main site, Physics, Maths, et al. But one cannot really complain if a user is following the established SE norms. But this user doesn't.

So my question is *how can this person be pleasantly persuaded to follow the SE norms?*

A bonus question is *should such persuasion be attempted?*

Answer (score 3):

It annoys me somewhat, since the questions come up on the main page even with good answers. But the structure of SE doesn't really promote anything to do this other than leaving a comment if it happens here. And theres no mechanism to handle this really in SE anyway.

My take is: If they do this here, leave a comment. Else, just ignore it. Most people are pretty much good at this here anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Gentle, persistent guidance, on each individual instance.

Don't try to address the overall pattern, just deal with each case. Politely, specifically and factually.

If the original asker comments on an answer in a manner than indicates it's exactly the answer they needed, you can comment right there suggesting they click the check to "accept" the answer. Don't try to address the overall pattern of never accepting answers; that's more likely to be taken personally or turn into an argument. You may want to include a link to the relevant help page:  https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Thanks. We (at EL&U) have been using the *Gentle, persistent guidance, on each individual instance ... Politely, specifically and factually*, but I haven't seen the link used.